# typeerror undefined is not a function liferay

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I am getting the `json` data from the server like `1,User,2,Courses,3,Organization` correctly, this data I am storing in a variable entities, now I am adding this json data for text field for auto complete and then allow multiple values for the text box(tabs) like in the below image.

[image],

I am getting the exception like `typeerror undefined is not a function` in the `alert('entities from the 466 line '+e);`

Can any one help me?

```javascript
AUI().ready('aui-textboxlist', function(A) {
try {
    alert('before calling selectEntities()'); 
    var entities = selectEntities();
    console.log(" entities "+entities);
    alert("entities from the server "+entities);

    entitiesBoxList = new A.TextboxList({
        contentBox: '#<portlet:namespace />entitiesDiv',
        dataSource: entities,
        matchKey: 'name',
        schema: {
            resultFields: ['id', 'name']
        },
        queryMatchContains:true,
        queryDelimiter : ',', 
        after: {
            render: function() {
                try{
                    var instance_ = this;
                    var index = 0;
                    this.entries.insert(index, entry);
                }catch (e) {
                    alert("exception raised at 461 line"+e);
                }
            }
        }
    }).render();        
} catch(e){
    alert('entities from the 466 line '+e);
}

}
```

Comment: If you comment out the line with this.entries like so:  `// this.entries.insert(index, entry);`, does it still happen? Another thing I could think of is that the `.render()` call is causing this. Your indentation is Very strange so it's hard to interpret the script, how about spending some time refactoring it to make it alittle more readable? You might find the error during that process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the above code works fine in Liferay-6.06, I am trying to migrate it to Liferay-6.2, so the AUI version in 6.06 is not works in 6.2:

```
    AUI().ready('aui-textboxlist-deprecated', function (A) {

        // code that uses A.TextboxList goes here
    });
```

the code is for 6.2. For 6.1, we have to use aui-textboxlist instead of aui-textboxlist-deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You said it is on the line with:

```
alert('entities from the 466 line '+e);
```

Then it's either saying your alert() is not a function (unlikely)
or something in your 'e' value. Since you said it contains JSON data, maybe it's because you aren't parsing the data correctly?

Possibly better: I noticed you have a function called selectEntities() on line 3. Maybe it's referring to that line and you have a binding issue.